# Manipulate user input for a list

Tags: python

I am putting the user input into a list, but I was wondering how to change the format for how the input is stored in the list, for example:

Code

```
lst = list(raw_input("Enter message: "))
```

User Input

```
ABABABAB
```

Output

```
['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B']
```

Desired Output

```
['AB', 'AB', 'AB', 'AB']
```

Comment: Use `raw_input("Enter message: ").split()`. Your output is missing spaces though, weird.

Comment: The user entered `ABABABAB` then, no spaces, for the output you showed.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: There are no spaces in the output, so no spaces were given in the input either..

Comment: By what rule are you splitting the input? groups of 2 letters? or groups of repeating patterns? can you give more samples? What if the input is ABCABCABC what should the output be?

Comment: My mistake, there are no spaces in the input, if I put spaces they are also included in the list

Comment: Related: [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)

Comment: @InbarRose For that input it should be 'AB', 'CA', 'BC' etc, so groups of 2 letters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `textwrap` module for splitting your string into even sized chunks:

Using your sample of input `ABABABAB`and chunking into groups of 2:

```
>>> import textwrap
>>> lst = textwrap.wrap(raw_input("Enter message: "), 2)
Enter message: ABABABAB
>>> lst
['AB', 'AB', 'AB', 'AB']
```

Using the sample I suggested with input `ABCABCABC` and chunking into groups of 2:

```
>>> lst = textwrap.wrap(raw_input("Enter message: "), 2)
Enter message: ABCABCABC
>>> lst
['AB', 'CA', 'BC', 'AB', 'C']
```

Notice how the extra letter is all on it's own.

Comment: I can't until 5 minutes has passed, I will then. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension with [`range`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range):

```
>>> user_input = 'ABABABABA' # user_input = raw_input("Enter message: ")
>>> [user_input[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(user_input), 2)]
['AB', 'AB', 'AB', 'AB', 'A']
```

Comment: Oops. Sorry :) +1 It works :) Cleaning up the comments