# python how to print space per n'th char

Tags: python

I have a big number in a variable, what I want is that  every 5'th  is separated ba a space

Code:

```
number = 123456789012345678901234567890
print "the number is:", number #Devide every 5'th
```

The output I want is:

```
The number is: 12345 67890 12345 67890 12345 67890
```

Comment: Use the solutions from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python) and then join the returned list using `str.join`.(Don't forget to convert number to a `string` or `list`)

Comment: This solution is also nice: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21162948/846892

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
In [1]: number = 123456789012345678901234567890

In [2]: num = str(number)

In [3]: print ' '.join(num[i:i+5] for i in xrange(0,len(num),5))
12345 67890 12345 67890 12345 67890
```

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly not elegant, but

```
rep = str(number)
line = ""
for i, char in enumerate(rep):
    line+=char
    if (i+1)%5 == 0:
        line+=" "
print line
```

Answer (score 0):

The most compact way is to do this with a regular expression.  For example:

```
>>> s ="123456789012345678901234567890"
>>> re.sub('(\d{5})', r'\1 ', s)
12345 67890 12345 67890 12345 67890
```

if you want to get all groups as a list you can do this:

```
>>> re.findall('(\d{5})', s)
['12345', '67890', '12345', '67890', '12345', '67890']
```

which you can then join:

```
>>> " ".join(re.findall('(\d{5})', s))
12345 67890 12345 67890 12345 67890
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had a general `grouper` function, this would be trivial:

```
print ' '.join(grouper(num, 5))
```

And it's easy to write that function. In fact, there are two different ways to do it.

---

Slicing—as in inspectorG4dget's answer—only works on sequences, and gives you an incomplete group if there's part of a group left at the end. If that fits your requirements—and for your question, it does—it's definitely simpler, and a little faster.

Here's a general-purpose grouper:

```
def grouper(sequence, n):
    return (sequence[i:i+n] for i in xrange(0, len(sequence), n))
```

---

Iterator grouping is more complicated, but it works on any iterable, even one-shot iterators, and is easy to customize for any of the three reasonable behaviors for trailing values.

You can find a recipe in the [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) docs, but here's a slightly shorter version (which truncates a partial group at the end):

```
def grouper(iterable, n):
    return zip(*[iter(iterable)]*n)
```

Or, if you install the [`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools) library, you can just `import` an implementation from there.

[How grouper works](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/08/how-grouper-works.html) explains how this implementation works.